# How to transfer some of my own reputation to a very nice effort but not exact answer?

Tags: support, reputation, thanks, appreciation

I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32256222/a-generic-way-to-create-a-checkable-context-menu-from-a-list-of-enum-values/32258536?noredirect=1#comment52398574_32258536) and received only one answer, a wrong one, but a really nice one. An awesome one. Although it is not answering fully the question, it brings good idea on how to partly fix my problem. The example is pretty big, fully functional and surely demand a lots of time to think and code.

I would like to give the user some of my reputation to thank him for its great proposed solution. His code made me a better programmer. I appreciate his great efforts. How can I show my recognition by giving him some of my reputation? Or there is another way to do that, that would be more tangible than a "Thank you!"?

Comment: I guess you could award a "Bounty"

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Comment: A bounty is not just for exact answer? I want to reward the effort!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) on the question to reward an exceptional answer.

A couple caveats:

- The question has to be 48 hours old. Your question isn't there yet, but will be soon.
- The bounty must be listed for 24 hours before you can award it.

Comment: No, the answer is not exact. I want to reward the effort. But marking the solution as ok will induce other people in error. I just want to say a real thanks to the person who give me very nice code and a great effort.

Comment: A bounty doesn't mark it as accepted. It's separate from the check mark.

Comment: Ha... ok!!! Thanks a lots

Answer (score 2):

How about notifying the user of the error, asking him to change it?

Then you can freely upvote and accept.

Also, note that the accept mark is just to show that it was a helpful answer, not necessarily correct. But I agree that it is better to wait.

You may also post your own correct answer if the other user doesn't respond to your suggestion.

Comment: I already tell the guy what's wrong. I will publish my answer for sure (it could help). On monday, if the person as corrected it's code and it works, it will be the accepted answer. Otherwise, if another working solution was proposed, it will be the accepted one. Otherwise it will be mine. But I will probably add a bounty and give it to the guy who made a great effort and have proposed very nice code. Thanks !!!

Comment: Please note that the minimal reputation spent on a bounty is 100 if you've posted an answer yourselves, as opposed to 50 otherwise.

Comment: I don't care that much about my reputation, mainly in this case. When I feel that somebody gave me lots of there time to help me, I think that it well worth 50 or 100 points. Thanks for the information , I red few minutes ago when KackerKarma point me a link about Bounty (as comments).